# runtime error accured when I run a VBA script to create a simple report out of text output in blocks

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub blockofdatatoreport()

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For i = 1 To 95     
    actvrw = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(what = i, searchdirection = xlNext).Row
    'searching cells top to bottom

    lr = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Find(what = "*", searchdirection = xlprevious).Row + 1
    'searching cells bottom to top

    For x = 1 To 5
        Sheet2.Cells(lr, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(actvrw + (x - 1), 3).Value
        'looping the first five columns in sheet2       
    Next

    For y = 1 To 4
        Sheet2.Cells(lr, 5 + y).Value = Sheet1.Cells(actvrw + (y - 1), 6).Value
        'looping the next four columns after the first four is done in sheet2
    Next        
    'You can also write like this or write a loop in two lines above.
    'Sheet2.Cells(lr, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(actvrw, 3).Value
    'Sheet2.Cells(lr, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(actvrw + 1, 3).Value
    'Sheet2.Cells(lr, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(actvrw + 2, 3).Value
    'Sheet2.Cells(lr, 4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(actvrw + 3, 3).Value
    'Sheet2.Cells(lr, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(actvrw + 4, 3).Value        
Next

End Sub
```

I get error called error 13 y type mismatch, what is in the above code causing the error??

Comment: your `Find` syntax is the issue. it needs to be `actvrw = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(what:= i, searchdirection:= xlNext).Row`, in all places. You should also prepare yourself to scenarios where `Find` failed

Comment: Always, first check, if you actually found something. Then start working from there. If nothing is found, you will get this error. See here for the standard `Range.Find` syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: Thanks a million this was very helpful. The syntax you suggested works! I am new to Excel-VBA . like it very much!